# How to loop through hrefs and add to new element's href for each post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Current loop just adds the first href (r.e., http://something.com/article-1) that's being stored to all hrefs with class "copy-item-link". I would like to duplicate the unique url from their corresponding list item and add to each element that includes "copy-item-class". Here's what I have so far before running any js.

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">
        <p class="item-link">
            <a href="http://something.com/article-1">Article 1</a>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <a class="copy-item-link">Read more</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p class="item-link">
            <a href="http://something.com/article-2">Article 2</a>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <a class="copy-item-link">Read more</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p class="item-link">
            <a href="http://something.com/article-3">Article 3</a>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <a class="copy-item-link">Read more</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fully open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance. Could use some help below...

```
var $readMore = (".copy-item-link");
var $item = (".item");

$($item).each(function() {
    var $itemLink = (".item-link a");

    $(this).each(function() {
        var $addLink = $($itemLink).attr('href');
        $($readMore).attr('href', $addLink);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing every `.item-link a` in each iteration, then updating every `.copy-item-link` as well.

You should just search in the current element:

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).find(".item-link a").attr('href');
    $(this).find('.copy-item-link').attr('href',url);
});
```

Comment: Yup. find() method is exactly what I needed to get it working. Thanks @amenadiel !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').each(function(){
   var item = $(this),
       url = item.find('.item-link a').attr('href');

   item.find('.copy-item-link').attr('href', url);
});
```